# Differentiating a derivative with respect to another function of $x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I've been studying second order differentials, during which we were taught how to reduce second order differential equations to a simpler form using substitution.

One trick we used was 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{dy}{dz}\bigg)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dz}\frac{dz}{dz}=\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}\frac{dz}{dx}$$
Where $y$ and $z$ are both functions of $x$

This was introduced by 'grouping' terms together to form $\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}$, which is not what is happening, just a useful trick that happens to work.

My question is, what is really happening here? Why does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick you claim is an abuse of mathematics.
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{dz}{dx}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{dz}{dx}\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}
$$
makes more sense as you can see the key change in the operator $d/dx$.

Comment: The chain rule works on differential operators? I did not know that, thanks!